# Can't display Generic List elements in ListView / Can't save elements in a generic list (C#, WPF, MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listview, mvvm

I know the title might sound confusing, but I am not sure where the issue exactly is. But let's start from the beginning.

I have this simple class

```
public class LessonListModel
{
    public string Lesson_Title { get; set; }
    public string Lesson_Parameter { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a method supposed to store SQL query in a generic list of objects of the class above

```
public List<LessonListModel> Obtain_Lesson_List(int Id, string Language)
{
    List<LessonListModel> LessonLista = new List<LessonListModel>();
    LessonListModel lessonListModel = new LessonListModel();
    using (var connection = GetConnection())
    using (var command = new SqlCommand())
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "select Lesson_Title, Lesson_Parameter from [Lesson] where Id_Course in (Select Id from [Course] where [Course_Name] = @language)";
        command.Parameters.Add("@language", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Language;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lessonListModel.Lesson_Title = reader["Lesson_Title"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(lessonListModel.Lesson_Title);
                lessonListModel.Lesson_Parameter = reader["Lesson_Parameter"].ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(lessonListModel.Lesson_Parameter);
                LessonLista.Add(lessonListModel);
            }
            LessonLista.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t", x));
        }
        
        return LessonLista;
    }
}
```

This is where the trouble already starts. I do not understand why, but all my elements are displayed by Console.WriteLine as

`ApkaJezykowa.MVVM.Model.LessonListModel`

eventhought the elements are queried properly. I genuiely don't know what is the reason why the data is not added to the list properly, or maybe it's just me not being able to display it properly.

And then here is XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="LV"
          Background="#484848"
          BorderBrush="Transparent"
          ItemsSource="{Binding LessonsList}"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="LV_SizeChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                        Width="230"
                        Height="40">
                            <Button
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Height="40"
                            Width="230"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                            Command="{Binding FrenchLessonUpdateViewCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Lesson_Parameter}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lesson_Title}"
                           Margin="0,0,0,0"
                           Style="{StaticResource Font_Style}"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Foreground="Black"/>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
    //It was just ItemContainerStyle part here, nothing important
</ListView>
```

Which, as you can guess, displays the elements in the same manner as in the Console.Writeline() instead of how it was supposed to be.

Here is also ViewModel, shortened just to the important part:

```
public class FrenchLessonViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<LessonListModel> lessonsList;
    private BaseViewModel _selectedViewModel;
    private ILessonRepository lessonRepository;

    public List<LessonListModel> LessonsList { get { return lessonsList; } set { lessonsList = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LessonsList)); } }

    public ICommand FrenchLessonUpdateViewCommand { get; set; }
    public FrenchLessonViewModel()
    {

        lessonRepository = new LessonRepository();
        LoadLesson();
    }

    public void LoadLesson()
    {
        if (ExerciseLevelModel.Instance.Level != 0 && ExerciseLevelModel.Instance.Language != null)
        {
            LessonsList = lessonRepository.Obtain_Lesson_List(lesson.Id, ExerciseLevelModel.Instance.Language);
            LessonsList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0}\t",x));
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried to rewrite the method multiple times, including from the questions posted here, it all kept ending up with the same result. Same with XAML, I really do not know where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: Just implement `ToString()` on LessonListModel

Comment: Implementing ToString is not necessary because there is a DataTemplate. The DataTemplate should however be inside `<GridViewColumn><GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>...</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate></GridViewColumn>`.

Comment: You are adding the same LessonListModel to LessonLista multiple times. Instead, create a new one for each item.

Comment: @Clemens In a sense that I should put 
LessonListModel lessonListModel = new LessonListModel(); 
inside while? Because I've done that and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Did you also fix the XAML? Why are you using a ListView with GridView for a single column, instead of the simpler ListBox?

Comment: I did, result is still the same. Also no particular reason, just used ListViews before for displaying fixed values, but I had to display different records this time and knew it's possible with listview. Simply did not think of using ListBox.

Comment: @Clemens I tried with adding a constructor to my class this time, but it still does not add elements properly, got any other ideas?

Comment: What difference should that make? Try your DataTemplate as the ItemTemplate of a LixtBox, and make sure there is nothing wrong in the ItemContainerStyle that you did not show us.

Comment: @Clemens removed that part completely for testing, used ListBox this time, issue remains the same. It has to be something with adding elements for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so it turned out that the execution of console.writeline instruction was just poorly executed and elements are being added properly.

> foreach (LessonListModel p in LessonsList) { Console.WriteLine(p.Lesson_Title, p.Lesson_Parameter); }

This is the correct way.

And for XAML itself, I've simply removed grid related elements and replaced listview.view with listview.itemtemplate.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="230"Height="40">
            <Button Style="{StaticResource NoMouseOver}"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    Height="40"
                    Width="230"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Margin="0,0,0,0"
                    Command="{Binding FrenchLessonUpdateViewCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Lesson_Parameter}">
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lesson_Title}"
                                           Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                           Style="{StaticResource Font_Style}"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           Foreground="Black"/>
                                                </Button>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```